# Trying to use function without second parameter

Tags: php, function, pdo, parameters

I've been trying to use a function without declaring its second parameter, but it doesn't seem to work. What have I done wrong?

I also tried declaring the function without the second parameter `$db->DoQuery($query, null);` with the same result.

```
<?php 
include($directory . "classes/database.php");
$db = new database;
$db->initiate();
include("../includes/core.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM services";
$db->DoQuery($query, null);
$num = $db->fetchAll();
print_r($num);
?>
```

Below is the database class.

```
<?php
class database {
  public function initiate() {
    $user             = "user";
    $password         = "pass";
    $hostname         = "localhost";
    $dbn              = "dbt";

    try
    {
      $this->database = new PDO("mysql:host={$hostname};dbname={$dbn}", $user, $password);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    { 
      $error = "I'm unable to connect to the database server.";
      die("Failed to connect to database: " . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $this->database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }

  public function DoQuery($query, $query_params) {
    try
    {
      $this->result = $this->database->prepare($query);
      if ($query_params != null)
      {
        $this->result->execute($query_params);
      }
      else
      {
        $this->result->execute();
      }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      die();
    }
  }

  // A function to fetch a single row from the query
  public function fetch() {
    return $this->result->fetch();
  }

  // A function to fetch multiple rows from the query
  public function fetchAll() {
    return $this->result->fetchAll();
  }

    // A function to fetch number of rows from the query
  public function RowCount() {
    return $this->result->RowCount();
  }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change in database class

```
public function DoQuery($query, $query_params = null) {
```

Call without 2nd parameter

```
$db->DoQuery($query);
```

Call with 2nd parameter

```
$db->DoQuery($query, null);
```

Comment: `$db->DoQuery($query, null);` doesn't work [**see**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Answer (score 0):

Set the second parameter to an `array()`

```
public function DoQuery($query, $query_params = array()) {
    try
    {
      $this->result = $this->database->prepare($query);
      $this->result->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      die();
    }
}
```

Then if you don't want to pass any query params, then simply omit the second parameter.

```
$db->DoQuery($query);
```